# Merge columns in rfc field optiond in azure adf

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Im using sap table connector . Under the rfctableoptions trying to merge columns as concat(column1,column2,column3) In (@{variables(Mergevalues)}). It ua throwing an error as nit able to parse the dynamic entry.
Im trying to concat 3 columns and checking the value.
How to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you provide a snip of how/where you are using concat under rfctableoptions? Also if you can provide some sample data of the columns, it will be helpful to reproduce.

Comment: Added the screenshot of how I'm trying to implement